# Mongodb sorting performance with index

Tags: mongodb, performance, sorting, indexing

MongoDb sorting performance with/without index
I have 500k test doucuments:

```
_id:5d5e5eb7f6ac46d3b0d88243
startDate:2019-08-23 13:08:34.377       (Date type)
duration:315532
_class:"Inviter Record"
```

I have simple index by startDate (ASC)
Sort my documents by query `{startDate: 1}` performance (using explain) with index:

> executionTimeMillis: 977

Without:

> executionTimeMillis: 356

I was expecting the opposite results

Answer (score 0):

I f***d up( Using sorting 500k documents without index i actually got 300+- milisec, but i also got executionStatus: false with error like you can't hold more than 32mb of data in RAM, please use index